# Chartboost adapter code error with Mopub mediation

Tags: android, mopub, chartboost

I am trying to integrate Chartboost (latest SDK) into Mopub using the following guide.
https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Third-Party-Ad-Networks

the mediation uses ChartboostInterstitial.java which requires ChartboostShared.java

however,there is a method call in ChartboostShared.java that returns an error "Cannot resolve CBFrameworkMoPub"

```
    Chartboost.setFramework(Chartboost.CBFramework.CBFrameworkMoPub);
```

does anyone have a workaround for this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When looking at the Charboost's fork of MoPub repo i think this line:

```
Chartboost.setFramework(Chartboost.CBFramework.CBFrameworkMoPub);
```

needs to be replaced with this one:

```
Chartboost.setMediation(Chartboost.CBMediation.CBMediationMoPub, "4.0.0"); //Needs Chartboost SDK 5.5.0+
```

Chartboost repo file:
https://github.com/ChartBoost/mopub-android-sdk/blob/master/extras/src/com/mopub/mobileads/ChartboostShared.java